# Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC - assuming assembly reference

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have just added Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC and when I open a view a warning appears:

```
Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' used by 'Kendo.Mvc' matches identity 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' of 'System.Web.Mvc', you may need to supply runtime policy
```

Here is the assembly in my Views\web.config

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </assemblies>
```

And here it is in my root web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I have been following the Telerik setup guide but it does not mention this issue.

Comment: Try to see the .csproj file and see around line 234 which contains `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` package. Also try to add `compilerOptions="/nowarn:1702"` on `<system.codedom>` section in web.config.

Comment: This is because the kendo dll are build referencing the old version. Program will still compile and work. See [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/system-web-mvc-v5-2-4-0)